# On what factors does the resolution of a neural network depend?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, artificial-intelligence

I have a neural network in keras. The network doesn't distinguish between two samples if they are 0.001 units apart from each other in the normalized feature space. It is extremely important for the network to be able to distinguish that because this difference isn't insignificant in the original (non-normalized) feature space.
Is there any way I can improve the resolution of my neural network? If so, what factors should I be changing?

Edit: Let me give you the code I'm using for my ANN.

Edit: Description of the dataset: I'm using a 2 dimensional dataset with x=[-1:1] and Y=[-1,1] with a step size of 0.001 between two consecutive points in both dimensions. Let the class labels be such that anything inside or on the circle with radius 0.5 and center at (0,0) be normal (class 1) and anything outside the circle be 0 (class 0). After training, I'm using the same training set as a test set. As it goes right now, the boundary points on the circle and a small neighbourhood inside and outside the boundary are being classified as 0.3 to 0.7. Only the points well within the circle are 1 and well outside the circle are 0. I recognise that this is the behaviour of a sigmoid activation function at the output layer. I need it to recognise the difference between a point on the boundary and a point lying just outside the boundary, 0.001 units away, and a point lying just inside the boundary, 0.001 units away.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split as tts
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping as es
from keras import optimizers as op
"""Creating the model"""
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12,input_dim=c,activation='relu')) #input layer (c is the dimensionality of my dataset)
for i in range(0,hidden_layer_size):
    model.add(Dense(12,activation='relu')) #hidden layers
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')) #output layer

"""Compiling the model"""
adam=op.Adam(lr=0.0007)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""Fit the model"""
early=es(monitor='acc',min_delta=0.0005,patience=2)
model.fit(features_train,labels_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=30,callbacks=[early],verbose=2)

"""Evaluation"""
scores=model.evaluate(features_test,labels_test)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Comment: do you have a repro example? your question is quite broad

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've included my ANN. Unfortunately, I cannot give out the data due to confidentiality issues.

Comment: Then provide a set of dummy data that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @Prune Yes, thank you. I've described a dummy dataset and the problem I'm facing in the edits.

Comment: My closure vote stands.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: For the information you've provided and the type of interaction you seem to want, you're on the wrong site.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really a concept of "resolution" in a neural network. If your model misclassifies some samples, then you either need a better model, or more data, or even additional regularization.

It is hard to predict what is wrong without testing the model extensively, so it is something you will have to do.

Comment: Thank you Matias. I'm not sure what you mean by classified equally. If you're saying that samples falling within a particular range of each other must be classified into the same class, then no. That wasn't what I was trying to do. I want the ANN to distinguish between say 1.000 and 1.001 and NOT give them the same class label. My training dataset contains samples separated by an order of 0.001, so I don't know why my ANN isn't learning that this separation is significant.

Comment: @PranavKoustubh Ah I see, for that then you just need a better model or a different normalization scheme.

Comment: I'm normalizing my inputs to [-1,1] range. My output labels are {0,1} for binary classification and no intermediate values. I can't seem to think of a better model. Maybe I lack the appropriate knowledge. What would you recommend?

Comment: @PranavKoustubh No, not really. This site is not to make suggestions, it is something you have to experiment with.

Comment: I understand that. But I was looking for some direction. Time is a factor for me and nothing worked so far. But thank you for your inputs.